# Get size of POST-request in PHP

Tags: php, post, size

Is there any way to get size of POST-request body in PHP?

Answer (score 43):

As simple as:

```
$size = (int) $_SERVER['CONTENT_LENGTH'];
```

Note that `$_SERVER['CONTENT_LENGTH']` is only set when the HTTP request method is POST (not GET). This is the raw value of the `Content-Length` header, as specified in [RFC 7230](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-3.3.2).

In the case of file uploads, if you want to get the **total size of uploaded files**, you should iterate over the `$_FILE` array to sum each `$file['size']`. The exact total size might not match the raw `Content-Length` value due to the encoding overhead of the POST data. (Also note you should check for upload errors using the `$file['error']` code of each `$_FILES` element, such as `UPLOAD_ERR_PARTIAL` for partial uploads or `UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE` for empty uploads. See [file upload errors](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php) documentation in the PHP manual.)

Comment: $size = (int) $_SERVER['CONTENT_LENGTH']; Does that give size in bytes unit?

Comment: deprecated ... $_SERVER['argv']

Comment: have in mind that this is what the browser reported, it may not be accurate due to e.g. limits in configuration, interrupted (partial) post.

Answer (score 6):

If you're trying to figure out whether or not a file upload failed, you should be using the PHP file error handling as shown at the link below. This is the most reliable way to detect file upload errors:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php

If you need the size of a POST request *without any file uploads*, you should be able to do so with something like this:

```
$request = http_build_query($_POST);
$size = strlen($request);
```

Comment: otherwise if he 'just' wants size, you can get it for a file by using the $_FILES array => $_FILES['nameoffile']['size']

Answer (score 5):

My guess is, it's in the `$_SERVER['CONTENT_LENGTH']`.

And if you need that for error detection, peek into `$_FILES['filename']['error']`.

Comment: I'm uploading large files on server along with other fields. But if I abort it part of the request will be missing, so I need to compare actual size of request body with the value from Content-Length header to ensure the file uploading wasn't aborted.

Comment: `$_SERVER['CONTENT_LENGTH']` of course contains the value from the header. I think it's PHP's responsibility to make sure it complies with the actual data being received. Maybe `$_FILES['file']['error']` has some hints for it?

Comment: If you're trying to detect failed file uploads, you should be doing it the way it's shown in my post, not counting bytes.

Comment: I have updated my answer to include reference to `$_FILES`. Thanks for confirmation, Keith.

Answer (score 3):

This might work :

```
$bytesInPostRequestBody = strlen(file_get_contents('php://input'));
// This does not count the bytes of the request's headers on its body.
```

Comment: Prior to PHP5.6 this action may clear the stream cause it's allowed to read it only once: [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php). So you will see it's length but then it will be empty

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are looking for [`$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA`](http://php.net/reserved.variables.httprawpostdata)

Comment: Hmm... But you don't need the data to know its size, do you?

Comment: Thanks, but $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA is not available with enctype="multipart/form-data". I need to use multipart/form-data to send files.

Comment: **Warning** This feature was DEPRECATED in PHP 5.6.0, and REMOVED as of PHP 7.0.0. [PHP Link](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.httprawpostdata.php)