# Detecting partially uploaded files?

Tags: php, file-upload, content-length

I have a webapp which reads from the php://input and it streams from it and than stores that data in a new file, however, because of this, a person might upload a file partially and it'll still be saved, so my question is: how can I make sure that every file which was uploaded this way was infact fully uploaded?

I guess it is something to do with content-length, but I haven't found any resources which talk about this.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should be able to retrieve the content length [from the HTTP header](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.13). After that it is just binary data. You cannot determine if the file was fully uploaded from the file information on the file system, of course.

See also: [Get size of POST-request in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1361451/get-size-of-post-request-in-php)

Comment: Might as well answer an old question for you  :)