# Get byte size of http request in PHP

Tags: php, api, post, httpcontext

Hi I am currently working on an integration of a merchant account system.

I need to get the totalbytes in a http request being sent to a url on my site. My site is written in PHP.

In C# it works as the following: but the main point to mention is how would I do this in PH as can't seem to find good documentation on this. Thanks in advance

```
 public void ProcessRequest (HttpContext context) 
{
    context.Response.Buffer = true;

    string response = "";
    string sMethod = "POST";

    //sUrl holds the address to the Verify service, this is a service from AllCharge 
    // that verifies the signature on the notification. This makes sure that the notification
    // was sent by AllCharge.

    //Demo server - use this address during the integaration, remark this line when working
    // with the live server
    string sUrl = "http://demo.allcharge.com/Verify/VerifyNotification.aspx";

    //Live server - use this address when working with the live server, remark this line 
    // during the integration
    //string sUrl = "https://incharge.allcharge.com/Verify/VerifyNotification.aspx";

    Int32 nCount = context.Request.TotalBytes;
    string formParameters = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(context.Request.BinaryRead(nCount));

}
```

Comment: Is `$_SERVER['CONTENT_LENGTH']` what you're looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that the best way for getting this for my use is by using:

```
$size = @file_get_contents('php://input');
```

Thanks for the help guys!

Comment: You must accept your own answer, so others having this issue could see it.

Answer (score 1):

The best I have ever been able to come up with is the following php function.

```
function findKb($content){
$count=0;
$order = array("\r\n", "\n", "\r", "chr(13)",  "\t", "\0", "\x0B");
$content = str_replace($order, "12", $content);
for ($index = 0; $index < strlen($content); $index ++){
    $byte = ord($content[$index]);
    if ($byte <= 127) { $count++; }
    else if ($byte >= 194 && $byte <= 223) { $count=$count+2; }
    else if ($byte >= 224 && $byte <= 239) { $count=$count+3; }
    else if ($byte >= 240 && $byte <= 244) { $count=$count+4; }
}
return $count;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$rqsize = (int) $_SERVER['CONTENT_LENGTH'];
```

Something like that was already asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1361451/get-size-of-post-request-in-php).

Answer (score 1):

```
$size = intval($_SERVER['CONTENT_LENGTH']);
```

`$size` should be the length of request.

Answer (score 1):

PHP is interpretation language, to do that in it rather difficult, try to use `memory_get_usage` function, here is the sample `http://it.php.net/manual/en/function.memory-get-usage.php`