# Get size of POST Request in Javascript

Tags: javascript, http, post

Is there any way to get size of POST-request body in JavaScript?

I see here it can be done in `PHP`

[Get size of POST-request in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1361451/get-size-of-post-request-in-php)

So I'm guessing it can be done in Javascript, anyone know how?

Here is how I am posting the data, but if I can't get the length this way and could another way I would like to know that also

```
var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = "/admin/get_info.py";
var params = "";
http.open("POST", url, true);
http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
http.onreadystatechange = function() {//Call a function when the state changes.
    if(http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {
        console.log(http.responseText);

    }
}
http.send(params);
```

Here is what I see in the developer console when sending the request.

[image]

The line referenced is this line `http.send(params);`

Thanks

Comment: It is not possible....

Comment: @user1844933 any explanation?

Comment: @spenf10 can you at least explain how you're `POST`ing the data? Synchronously, asynchronously, via `jQuery`, `XMLHttpRequest`?

Comment: PHP is typically the *receiving* end of the request, while Javascript is typically the *originating* end of the request. They're not quite comparable. However, since it's you sending the data, you should be able to figure out how much data you're sending. A practical example for where you need this would be helpful.

Comment: @Leo I am doing `XMLHttpRequest`  see above

Comment: @deceze well when sending my data with Javascript I am getting an error saying `POST http://example.com/admin/save_info.py 413 (Request Entity Too Large)`

Comment: So how does it help you to get the size of the request? Either you need to change your server to accept larger requests if you need to send large requests, or you need to change your sending behaviour to send smaller requests in general.

Comment: @deceze well the server says the max size is 7MB and I am only sending a file that is 1.2MB but I encode it to base64 which would increase it but should increase it that much, so I want to confirm my POST is about 1.4MB

Comment: @spenf10 are you sure is 7MB or 7KB? ;)

Comment: Look at your browser's network inspector debug console.

Comment: @spenf10 what web server are you using?

Comment: @Leo I am using dreamhost

Comment: @deceze look at what in the browser's network inspector debug console, thats where I see the error

Comment: And that's also where you can see the request and its size...!?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/profile/network-performance/resource-loading

Comment: @spenf10 isn't dreamhost a hosting provider? NOT a web server?

Comment: @Leo yes you are correct I misread your question. the server is running apache

Comment: @deceze thanks I looking there I added to question what I see there when I submit the POST

Answer (score 0):

This is got to do the content you are sending. The size of the content is equal to the size of whatever you're passing in the `send` method...in bytes...

```
http.send(params);
```

This error comes from the server because it doesn't accept the size of the request content as explained here

http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html

All major web servers (IIS, Apache, etc.) allow you configure the max request size allowed.

If you're using Apache you can specified a larger request size limit in the `httpd.conf` file

Answer (score 0):

(2022 answer)
I cannot see exactly what you are trying to send with your code (`params = ''` ??)

Normally on would want to send form data from a web page. Nowadays there is the [`FormData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) object and you could do something like that with it:

```js
$('button').on('click', function() {
  const fd = new FormData(this.form)
  let size = 0
  
  for(let pair of fd.entries()) {
    if (pair[1] instanceof Blob)
      size += pair[1].size
    else
      size += pair[1].length
  }
  
  alert('Form data size (bytes): ' + size)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input type="text" name="text">
  <input type="file" name="file">
  <button type="button">Form Size</button>
</form>
```

Note that the snippet shows only the size of the form data. The size of the POST request will be bigger as it contains headers, cookies, the names of the form fields, plus for every form field things like:

```
...
------WebKitFormBoundarybx0rDPTOp9n573wK
Content-Disposition: form-data; field_name = "<...>"

<Value>
...
```

Normally the biggest part of the payload would be the uploaded files (if any).

Using the function from the snippet and adding some more margin kilobytes for the headers/etc. you could practically estimate the POST request size quite well in order to avoid the `HTTP Error 413.1 - Request Entity Too Large` error in a browser client side validation.