# How to get php://input size?

Tags: php

Building a stream implementation for my API by implementing the PSR-7 StreamInterface.  In my testing I use `php://input`but for some reason it will not calculate the correct size.  It is returning `null`.  It works correctly for other files, however.

```
class Stream implements StreamInterface
{
    public function __construct($resource)
    {
        $this->resource = $resource;

        $this->meta = $this->getMetadata();

        $this->size = $this->calculateSize();

        $this->isReadable = $this->isModeable('readable');
        $this->isWritable = $this->isModeable('writable');
    }

    private function calculateSize()  // RETURNS NULL FOR PHP://INPUT??
    {
        $stats = fstat($this->resource);  // this is evaluating to false;

        return isset($stats['size']) ? $stats['size'] : null;
    }
}
```

I'm thinking that maybe I cannot do this with `php://input` and what I will need to do is inherit from my `Stream` class and override these methods specifically for `php://input`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`php://input` is not a file, so `fstat()` doesn't have anything to process.

So, yes, you are going to have to special-case `php://input`

Answer (score 3):

> php://input is a read-only stream that allows you to read raw data
>   from the request body. In the case of POST requests, it is preferable
>   to use php://input instead of $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA as it does not
>   depend on special php.ini directives.

in order to read the size of the http post request

```
$rqsize = (int) $_SERVER['CONTENT_LENGTH'];
```

offical doc : http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php

refernce doc : [Get size of POST-request in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1361451/get-size-of-post-request-in-php)

Comment: May be it's not what you want, but this is the only way... :(