# how to get size of request and response in laravel

Tags: laravel

I had this code in a middleware that used to log the data traffic in a laravel application

```
    public function terminate($request, $response)
    {
        $method = strtoupper($request->getMethod());

        $uri = $request->getPathInfo();

        $message =now()."- {$method} {$uri} - Request Size{ $request_size } - Response Size{ $response_size }\n";
        file_put_contents(storage_path("requests.log"), $message,"\r\n".FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
    }
```

I want to know the request and response size , how to do it ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1361451/get-size-of-post-request-in-php for request size and `strlen` for response size

Comment: explain please ..

Comment: There is the link above, which explains how to get the request size. For response, I suppose it's JSON, you have to measure the length of it through function `strlen`