# input post array in CodeIgniter have a limit?

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3, bulkinsert

currently doing a bulk upload. After upload the excel file, user can validate the data then click submit to save. After user click submit, the row inserted in database only 43 rows. I have upload file with 50 rows, but after click submit its only save 43 rows. But when view after upload its okay, its display all 50 rows. But when I click submit button, its only insert 43 rows in database.

My question is how come its only insert 43 rows only, not 50 rows that i have import? is there any solution for this problem? Im using codeigniter 3

Here is the image the display after upload excel file
[image]

Here I attach the code for submit

```
public function saveBudgetBulk() {
        $now = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

        $job_sender_name = $this->input->post('job_sender_name');
        $job_sender_contact = $this->input->post('job_sender_contact');
        $tot = $this->input->post('total_row');

        $this->db->trans_begin();

        for ($k = 0; $k < $tot; $k++) {
            $xx = array(
                'job_sender_name' => $job_sender_name[$k];
                'job_sender_contact' => $job_sender_contact[$k],
                "tot" => $tot,
                "k" => $k,
            );
            $this->db->insert('job_uat', $xx);
        }


        if ($this->db->trans_status() == FALSE) {
            $this->db->trans_rollback();
            $result = 0;
            echo "Fail to save";
        } else {
            $this->db->trans_commit();
            $result = 1;

            redirect('client/job');
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please, specify the version of the CodeIgniter framework you're currently using. In addition, set a [relevant "question tag"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging).

Comment: Have you checked what the PHP config option `max_input_vars` is set to?

Comment: I have checked it, mine is 6000

Comment: What do you get when you try to check the [HTTP `POST` request body size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1361451/get-size-of-post-request-in-php)?

Comment: if i check $tot = sizeof($job_sender_name); , i got only 44.

Comment: Please try using  `log_message('error', (int) $_SERVER['CONTENT_LENGTH'])` instead to check the size.